# CRUD with date, how to edit the date?

Tags: php, laravel

```
In my model
```

```
protected $casts = [
    'reception_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

In my controller

```
$machine->reception_date = $reception_date;
```

In blade

```
<label htmlFor="date" className="date-style">
  <span id="dateFecha">Fecha de Recepción</span>
  <input type="date" value="{{$machine->reception_date}}" name="date" className="date-input-style"/>
</label>
<br>
```

I need to know how can I update the date, thank you...

Answer (score 0):

after you get the date from input you have to save it:

```
$machine->save();
```

or you can create an instance in DB with create if you activate mass_assignment like this:

```
Machine::create([
"reception_date" => $request->date,
//other fields you need
]);
```